# Why is validation not being run onSubmit in Redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have the following react redux-form below to provide the user with a form to enter one or more emails.

For some reason, validate is not being run onSubmit. I added a console log and only see the validate function being run when the page is loaded.

What am I doing wrong to cause validate not to run onSubmit?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, FieldArray, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'

let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error}}) =>
  <fieldset>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} name="email" type="text" className="form-control" />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </fieldset>

let renderEmails = ({fields, meta: {submitFailed, error}}) =>
    <div>

    {fields.map((email, index) =>
      <div className="row form-group" key={index}>

        <div className="col-6">
          <Field
            name={email}
            component={renderEmailField}
            label={`Email Address`}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          {index > 2 &&
            <a href onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); fields.remove(index)}}>X</a>
          }
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          {submitFailed && error &&
            <span className="error">{error}</span>
          }
        </div>

      </div>
      )}

      <div className="row form-group">
        <div className="col">
          <p>
            <a href onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); fields.push()}}>Add Email</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

class RaterInviteForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    // stuff
  }

  render() {

    const { submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="RaterInviteForm">
        <h1>Invites</h1>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <FieldArray name="emails" component={renderEmails} />
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" disabled={submitting} className="btn btn-primary">Send Invitations</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  console.log('validate')
  if (!values.emails || !values.emails.length) {
    errors.emails = {_error: 'At least one email must be entered'}
  }
  else {
    let emailsArrayErrors = []
    if (emailsArrayErrors.length) {
      errors.emails = emailsArrayErrors
    }
  }
  return errors
}

RaterInviteForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
  initialValues: {
    emails: ['', '', '']
  },
  validate
})(RaterInviteForm)
...
```

Comment: As the docs state (http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/examples/submitValidation/), can you try to pass your `submit` function to `this.props.handleSubmit()`? As in `onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(submit)`. You would also remove `validate` from `reduxForm({})`.

Comment: So how do you resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the up to date version I would try what the docs show is the correct method for implementing submit validation.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody any chance you can be a little more specific? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Redux Form docs/example](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/examples/submitValidation/) show it should be done like the following example.

You should pass your `submit` validation function to `this.props.handleSubmit()`, as in `onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(validate)}`.

```
class RaterInviteForm extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const { submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="RaterInviteForm">
        <h1>Invites</h1>
        <form className="form" onSubmit=    {this.props.handleSubmit(validate)}>
          <FieldArray name="emails" component={renderEmails} />
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" disabled={submitting} className="btn btn-primary">Send Invitations</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  console.log('validate')
  if (!values.emails || !values.emails.length) {
    errors.emails = {_error: 'At least one email must be entered'}
  }
  else {
    let emailsArrayErrors = []
    if (emailsArrayErrors.length) {
      errors.emails = emailsArrayErrors
    }
  }
  return errors
}

RaterInviteForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
  initialValues: {
    emails: ['', '', '']
  }
})(RaterInviteForm)
...
```

Comment: FYI, given I'm using fieldArrays, I believe I'm doing this correctly- look at the Field Array Example here: http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/examples/fieldArrays/

Answer (score 1):

By Default validation is run on blur event .

And also, by Default submitFailed (redux form props) is set to False . This props only get true if validation is approved and then you can submit the form .

So you can either use onHandleSubmit which expect function as a parameter. 
Example

```
onSubmit={handleSubmit(validate)}
```

Or you can just add this in

```
RaterInviteForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'emailsForm',
touchOnBlur : false 
  initialValues: {
    emails: ['', '', '']
  },
  validate
})(RaterInviteForm)
```

What this does is , it validates form only when you submit the form .